# gatsby not installing

Tags: gatsby

As the title says I tried everything under the sun. Delete/update NPM/node (including folders package-lock), delete every package, start a new folder, change all the global settings, update all the global settings. (cache clean/cache verified). Updated all plugins required

warning message:

[image]

Still getting the same warning no matter if I'm in a Global or new folder. Yes I have the most updated NPM, yes I have admin access, yes the global changes takes in npm it shows js-core3 for example but when trying to run npm gatsby install still gives me an error saying I'm running an older version of js-core. anyone who can help me?  I'm on a PC I'm just trying to get the setup shown on gatsby YT and run the command gatsby but it doesn't work

Comment: Those are `warnings`, no `errors`. Can you provide a more detailed log of your errors?

Comment: Oh I miss spoke however gatsby is still not working when trying the gatsby command basically was trying to just get the install set up without any success.. also downloaded the Gatsby bootcamp. on YT

Comment: warnings doesn't block or fail the develop, if your Gatsby application is not working there should be an `error` somewhere. What error are you facing?

Comment: I guess NPM is not installing gatsby and showing me this  : The term 'gatsby' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fit [some pre-requisites](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/part-zero/) to install Gatsby in your machine, plus some minor adjustments if using Windows.

- Make sure you have Node installed
- Make sure you have Git instaled
- Install Gatsby-cli globally:

  `npm install -g gatsby-cli`

  Make  sure it works by: `gatsby --help`

  - In [Windows](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-on-windows/), you may need to add:

    `npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015`

When installing global dependencies, make sure to close and reopen the terminal to delete the cache.

---

> The term 'gatsby' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1

You may find some workarounds in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/20163).

Comment: wow that windows-build command worked perfectly thanks!!